# Entity Framework in .NET?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, installation

Do we need to install the entity framework separately or does it come with .net 3.5

Comment: Here's an article on usage of EF in dotnet 3.5 http://mywpf-visu.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-use-entity-framework-35-with.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate install. It appears you can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7fd7164e-9e73-43f7-90ab-5b2bf2577ac9&displaylang=en).

Comment: While he didn't specify, I doubt the CTP is what he is after.

Comment: Jacerhea: Fair enough; I did try and find the proper version but failed, so I just linked to that one. Feel free to correct my post and mark it CW, or something, so that it has the correct info.

Answer (score 5):

It comes with .Net 3.5 [Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en)